# Alias works from well from the cli but no if it is set on aliases.sh file

Tags: linux

I have written a short alias called shared as is showed on the screenshots. The alias is suppose to takes me out to the permanent_mount/data/department directory, where department could be finance,hr or ops according to the user running the alias. The alias works well from the CLI but if the alias is set on the aliases.sh file and runnning it from there, it takes me out to /permanent/data directory. Why?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because your alias definition is delimited with double quotes, variables inside are expanded at the time of definition. So, whatever `b` happens to be at the time you do your `alias shared=...` gets built into the `cd` command at the end of your alias. You need to use single quotes to prevent variable expansion, or use `\$b` as an alternative, to prevent variable expansion.